# Making TFS2017 to use MSBuild 16

Tags: msbuild

Is there any way to make TFS2017 to use MSBuild 16? Some of my projects which getting updated to the latest NuGet packages can't compile in an older release of MSBuild due to the Fody package. I've installed the VS2019 build tools including MSBuild  16 on the server but the server is still not able to use this version. Even the build agent on the server directly still uses the older MSBuild version.

After a bit of searching, I read in a lot of threads about modifing the build process template but where can I find this?

Comment: XAML based build or the new Azure DevOps style builds? The best way is to upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2019, that's the officially supported way to support MSBuild 16.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing. I already thought that the upgrade is the cleanest way. I‘m just always a bit afraid to change my backend systems because I‘m not very experienced with it. But I think I will try it after a whole system and database backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Making TFS2017 to use MSBuild 16

Just like you said, to use MSBuild 16 with Azure DevOps Server 2017, update the Azure DevOps Server 2017 to 2019 is the cleanest way.

Besides, If you have any concerns about upgrading Azure Devops Server, you can try the following method before you start.

Using MSBuild task instead of Visual Studio build and configure MSBuild to point to my MSBuild 16.0 folder:

- Add MSBuild to your build steps
- Select the Specify Location option like the image below:

[image]

Then add the local path of MSBuild 16.0.

Hope this helps.